# What can you do about being forced to sit next to a very large passenger?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, seating

My mum is up in arms about that fact that she **sat next to a (very) obese gentleman on her flight causing sufficient discomfort for her to grab the cabin jumpseat in cruise**.
The flight was a fully-booked shorthaul flight with BA from Heathrow.

Few airlines are willing to go the distance which for instance Southwest does with their *customer of size* policy, what can you do in this situation when it becomes unbearable?

Comment: Speak to the cabin crew?

Comment: [29 Sumo wrestlers on a plane](http://boingboing.net/2014/07/31/29-sumo-wrestlers-on-a-plane.html)

Comment: Whatever the situation, the traveler will have 10x the options *before the door closes*.  If you are in this situation, the Gate Agent is best person to resolve it.

Comment: Except you won’t know who you’re sitting next to until both of you boarded the plane (@Johns-305)

Comment: @Jan Unless your seatmate is the last to board, and there are no other issues with closing the flight, there's time to go forward to speak to them.  Once they close the door, your stuck with whatever is on board.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It is not a pleasant situation for both of them - the passenger or the large passenger. It is very uncomfortable for the passenger and totally embarrassing for the large guy. In addition to that, it is uncomfortable and embarrassing for the staff.

Unfortunately, there is no one single rule that applies here; each airline has its own policy regarding this.

### What you should do before the flight takes off

If the large person's body is invading your space and you have noticed this during boarding, make sure to speak to one of the cabin crew members immediately. Make it their problem. You are paying for a seat and it is your right to get a full seat, not a part of one.

Remember, **the only time you can report this case is on the ground**. It is the perfect time for crew or ground staff to find another seat either for you or for the large person, or to find another solution in the case that there are no spare seats. Once the doors are closed and the plane is moving without you talking about it, you have given complicit agreement to this situation and no one can do much about it in most cases.

### What the staff will do

This depends on the airline. Some airlines make large people pay; some others upgrade large people to business or first class for free as a part of their services (the airline I work for does this if no two seats are available in economy class). You could get lucky and get moved to a higher class and leave your seat for the other passenger. Either way, your problem should be solved before the plane takes off.

## Things to keep in mind

This is an odd and embarrassing situation. Make sure to talk in private with the cabin crew to avoid embarrassing the sized passenger publicly. Depending on the airline, the sized passenger can be deplaned from the airplane or asked to pay for an extra seat. You may also be asked if you would like to wait for another flight! Anything is possible if no extra seats are available.

Comment: It is suprising that airlines have very strict rules on luggage, but not on passenger sizes.

Comment: @Berhard: Like a cage at the gate? "All passengers must be able to fit within this cage to be allowed boarding!" That would be very convenient. Or how would you define passenger size? (sarcasm intended)

Comment: @Bernhard Taking into account that having extra rules for "well-sized" people is a sort of discrimination, which needs to be carefully defended from a legal point of view, it is not. After all, you cannot discriminate against a piece of luggage.

Comment: Not to go too off-topic, but this is why I personally think that anti-discrimination rules should only apply if there are no logical reasons to discriminate. Firing someone because they're female or black is not a logical reason. telling an obese passenger that they have to book an extra seat because they don't fit a standard seat is a logical reason (can't fit someone with a 2 foot wide gut in a 1.5 feet seat).

Comment: @NateKerkhofs "Logical" is unfortunately not an objective criteria. I am sure that you'll find enough people finding it completely logical that they won't be driven by a female taxi driver or treated by a black doctor.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo There is no scientific basis that a female cannot be an adequate driver, nor that a doctor knows less about medicine because they're black. However, there is scientific basis that a passenger with a 2 foot wide gut cannot fit in a 1.5 foot seat. those "logical" reasons for racism or sexism have nothing to do with science, but with deeply-rooted religious, political or social thoughts that have no scientific basis. But I don't wish to touch this subject anymore except maybe in chat. Let's just say with "Logical", I mean "with a scientific basis".

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: to an extent you already have what you want, at least in the UK. It wouldn't be held to be discrimination to assert that a 2-foot-wide person doesn't fit in a 1.5-foot-wide seat. However, it *would* be held to be discrimination to choose a size and refuse to make any provision for people above that size even where it is reasonably possible for a service provider to do so. The line is drawn higher than you'd like though: you say discrimination should apply only where there's *no* logical reason, in fact it applies where there's some logical reason but it's deemed surmountable.

Comment: Examples: in the UK it's not lawful to make a woman redundant rather than a man even if statistically women take more maternity leave and so are more expensive to employ (I don't know whether that's even still true, it used to be). It's not lawful to give a woman a lower car insurance premium than a man with the same driving record, even though the actuaries say women claim less. AFAIK it *is* lawful to offer a man a cheaper annuity than a woman with the same health record, since the same actuaries say the woman lives longer. Rules for large passengers enter this difficult arena.

Comment: Point of interest: At what point does a larger body become a safety concern? When they get jammed in the aisle? Amusingly, tall people like myself moan endlessly about leg room but wide people are not allowed to do the same? I've been on flight where my hip bones are rammed against the seat sides and it is thoroughly uncomfortable. And I'm rather slim!

Comment: I am obese (a UK size 24) lady, and hate plane seats. I personally don't think I take up anyone else's personal space, but I do like to have the arm rest up to give me a bit more room (I only do this if I know the person next to me, so I prefer to travel with family members). For me my thighs are the widest part, which get wider when I sit down. If the arm rests were slightly higher, than it would be a lot more comfortable for me because my legs would fit underneath them, and I would still fit on my own seat. I really hope other passengers don't think of me like the OP does.

Comment: @emmalgale I worked as a cabin crew for a decade, it is very rare for sized people to cause any problem, some passengers are a$$e$ by birth, they would complain about anything, they just need the smallest reason to do so, so if they see a sized passenger, they would just complain to be moved most likely just to be moved to another seat and not because the sized passenger, we usually move them to a real shitty seat (the middle one) just to see them ask us to move them back.. it happens all the time.

Comment: @MeNoTalk large people have enough going against them, they know the problems they have themselves and don't want to push those on others. It's the skinny photomodel sized ones that cause trouble, scream about how "unfair" it is that they're having to sit next to someone who's overweight and wants to use the armrest... And with airline seats becoming more and more cramped, it's only going to get worse.

Comment: I have had to sit next to a non-fat person with extremely wide shoulders (and mine are nto too narrow themselves) was extremely uncomfortable. But yes fat or skinny ash nothing to do with it, it is the width of your body's widest point - hips, shoulders, mid-rif, ... that has to be taken into effect. So do not discriminate just based on fat, a huge body builder could make your seat even less comfortable

Comment: @Bernhard It would be nice if they combine both, something like: "A passenger and his/her luggage must not exceed 107 kg". This will be nice!

Comment: @MeNoTalk Samoa Air actually do "[pay by weight](http://www.samoaair.ws/index.php/booking-2/pay-by-weight)". Personally I think that making people pay by weight discriminates against so many different types of people that it probably wouldn't be legal in a lot of countries. Do wheelchair users get charged more because they have to factor in the weight of their wheelchair? Not exactly fair is it?! I wish I would have the confidence to complain if I got sat next to someone who was so up themselves that they couldn't bear to sit next to someone who isn't their idea of perfect!

Comment: @emmalgale You could also turn the argument is it fair for small people to pay for overweight passengers? I don't think so. It is more fair for everybody being entitled to bring a fixed amount of weight, both personal weight and luggage. If you are small you can bring much more luggage then those who weigh a bit more. I have seen the most fair system in south america where everybody was entitled for 100 kg.

Comment: @menotalk this system already exist on certain flight in the amazon rain forest. I really like this system, since it also provide people with an incentive to loose weight. The only person who are "discriminated" are long people. With 1.90m in length I am such a person, but I don't mind paying a bit extra, because my length also brings the benefit the FAs ofter ask me to sit at the emergency exit, which comes with extra leg space.

Comment: @andra If you pay more you can also expect to get more space on the plane, but I don't think that will happen anytime soon.

Comment: Pay by weight is a fundamentally flawed idea, unless we're talking about small planes, where the extra weight actually matters. When you buy a ticket, you're paying for a seat and some space in the cargo hold. If you require an entire seat, the opportunity costs for allowing you in the plane are basically independent of your weight, so there's no reason the airline should give you any discount. The cargo hold also doesn't get any bigger, if you're a small person, so you can't check in more luggage.

Comment: @JouniSirén there is a real reason why lifting 130kg to 38,000ft costs more than lifting 60kg.  Admittedly it isn't anything like the amount that they charge you for being 20kg over your baggage.

Comment: @JouniSirén weight doesn't matter in big planes? I guess computer says "no": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lksDISvCmNI

Comment: You can do the math yourself. In a typical medium-haul passenger jet, there is around 2 kg of aircraft for every 1 kg of payload. For long-haul jets, the ratio is around 3:1. Fuel costs are usually around 30% of the total operating expenses. As a rough estimate, if you and your luggage weight only 50% of the average, you might get a 5% discount on medium-haul flights and a 4% discount on long-haul flights. Extra luggage fees exist mostly to keep the total amount of luggage small enough that everything fits in the plane. Air freight is much cheaper.

Comment: I would only be willing to pay extra to haul my weight around if I was also provided with a seat that was more comfortable. It really wouldn't be an incentive for me to lose weight - I just wouldn't fly! There are quite a few medical conditions that cause weight gain, so it is really unfair to assume that overweight people are like that by choice.

Comment: @NobodySpecial Jouni is correct. The fee for a 20kg overweight bag is primarily because of the baggage handlers, not because of the fuel cost. There are rules for what a single handler can be required to lift. As far as the math is concerned, a 777-300ER weighs 370,000 lb. empty. It then carries up to another 327,000 lb. of fuel (this will be burned in flight, so we'll say 163,000 lb. avg.) If all 300 pax weighed an additional 150 lb., that would still increase the weight by less than 10%, even ignoring baggage. With fuel at 30% cost, that's a 3% cost increase for doubling pax weight.

Comment: I wish I had seen this and taken this advice. I'm a fairly broad shouldered gent and on a recent flight on a Dash 8, I was seated next to a very large kiwi girl. I estimate I had no more than 75% of my seat available to me. She was very nice and did apologise so I didn't want to make a fuss and cause any undue embarassment. The problem was though was the contoured seats ended up digging into my ribs after shifting my seating position for an hour. I had issues with my ribs and back for about 6 weeks as a result.

Answer (score 6):

It's a health and safety issue. Depending on the airline and jurisdiction, they may have a legal duty to ensure you are not injured by being squashed up. A few years back a woman travelling with Virgin Atlantic received compensation for just such an injury, so most airlines are at least aware of the liability.

As Nean says, report it to the cabin crew. Don't be tempted to discuss it with the obese passenger, because even if they promise to try to keep from squashing you, they might fall asleep and do it anyway.

http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/wales/2346319.stm

Answer (score 2):

Find a different seat.

One way to do this is to bring cash. After you board, if you happen to be in a seat you don't like (e.g. because the person next to you is large), find a more preferable seat that seems to have a solo passenger in it, and make an attractive cash offer to the person who currently has that seat to switch with you. Be upfront with your reason for wanting to switch, as they will likely be suspicious otherwise.

Comment: seems...quite sketchy, proably against the rules of most airlines.